# Ramdom sort of image plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slider

Does anyone knows where I could find a plugin similar to this website 
https://www.invisionapp.com/enterprise ? I like how does the logos on after the video section works.

Comment: Just Google _"Parallax Scrolling Plugin"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vanilla-jquery example implementation (text-only, but you can apply it to images, as well)

```js
const logoOptions = [
    "lyft",
    "invision",
    "ibm",
    "google",
    "apple",
    "tesla",
    "coke",
    "pepsi"
];

function changeLogo() {
    const logos = $(".logos").children();
    const logoNames = logos.toArray().map(i => i.attributes.getNamedItem("data-company").textContent);

    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length);
    const logo = $(logos.get(index));

    const fLogoOptions = logoOptions.filter(i => logoNames.indexOf(i) === -1);
    const newLogo = fLogoOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * fLogoOptions.length)];

    logo.fadeOut(1000, function () {
        logo.text(newLogo).data('company', newLogo);

        logo.fadeIn(1000, function () {
            setTimeout(changeLogo, 1000);
        });
    });
}

setTimeout(changeLogo, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logos">
  <div data-company='lyft'>lyft</div>
  <div data-company='invision'>invision</div>
  <div data-company='ibm'>ibm</div>
  <div data-company='google'>google</div>
</div>
```

Honestly, you don't even need jQuery *(it would probably clean it up a little bit, too)*.